# Funcionamento de um Editor de Textos Online

Tags: aplicação-web

Galera, alguém poderia me dar um help.

Tenho uma dúvida de como é salvo os dados de um editor de textos online no estilo google docs, lá acontece de forma automática, mas a questão pra mim é, como ? via API ? alguma coisa do tipo Socket.io ? estou com muita dificuldade para entender como isso acontece, como o dado é enviado para o servidor, alguém consegue me ajudar ?

Fico imaginando, uma pessoa vai lá e escreve três páginas, porém após continuar escrevendo após a terceira página, como eu salvo apenas o conteúdo modificado ? ou sempre terei de salvar tudo ?

Comment: Olha, é uma boa pergunta. Mas você já tentou abrir o console do chrome nesta página e rastrear as requisições POST que são enviadas? Nelas poderá tirar todas as suas dúvidas.

Comment: Não tinha pensando nisso Diego, com certeza vou tentar.

Comment: Boa! Depois compartilha conosco as suas descobertas... :)

Comment: Acredito que os eventos estao no `onChange` respeitando alguma regra, como aguardar alguns segundos desde o ultimo change. A forma se por API, Socket ou etc com certeza depende da ferramenta, nao significa que Google, Microsoft ou voce deve fazer igual.

Comment: Galera estive analisando um site com uma funcionalidade deste tipo, este Site em questão utiliza API, e sempre que ele checa alterações ele executa um PUT com todo o texto, ele não verifica se ouve alterações ou algo do tipo, ele simplesmente envia tudo, SEMPRE ! e não fica ruim, pois é enviado apenas texto, claro que dependendo do conteúdo a ação 'SALVAR' demora um tempo, mas nada que afete a usabilidade da ferramente, porém ainda vou pesquisar mais